# Store.findBy() acting crazy?

Tags: extjs

I have been debugging this for days. `Store.findBy(function (record, id)`
not behaving. Or maybe it me misbehaving. Have put the JSON in the code so it is easy to test. FindBy() is matching 12345 and there is no 12345 and it comes back with an index of 0 and foo. What am I doing?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {

        var theJson = {
            "users": [{
                "user": {
                    "id": 0 ,
                    "name": "foo" ,
                    "age": 22 ,
                    "skills": [{
                        "type": "bowcrafting" ,
                        "skillLevel": 50 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    }]
                }} , {
                "user": {
                    "id": 1 ,
                    "name": "bar" ,
                    "age": 71 ,
                    "skills": [{
                        "type": "fencing" ,
                        "skillLevel": 32 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    } , {
                        "type": "swordsmanship" ,
                        "skillLevel": 73 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    }]
                }} , {
                "user": {
                    "id": 2 ,
                    "name": "foobar" ,
                    "age": 132 ,
                    "skills": [{
                        "type": "tactics" ,
                        "skillLevel": 90 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    } , {
                        "type": "carpentery" ,
                        "skillLevel": 86 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 75, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    } , {
                        "type": "hiding" ,
                        "skillLevel": 100 ,
                        "levels": [10, 25, 50, 65, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 99, 100]
                    }]
                }
            }]
        };

        var jstore = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['id', 'name', 'age', 'skills'] ,
            data : theJson,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory' ,
                reader: {
                    type: 'json' ,
                    root: 'users' ,
                    record: 'user' ,
                    idProperty: 'id'
                }
            } ,

            autoLoad: true
        });

        Ext.create ('Ext.button.Button', {
            text: 'Push me' ,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody () ,
            handler: function (btn) {
                var index = jstore.findBy (function (user, id) {
                    // Here's the hint
                    if (user.data.skills.skillLevel === 12345) return id;
                    else return -1;
                });

                console.log ('index = ', index);

                if (index != -1) {
                    // It will print 'foo' because it's the user
                    // that has the skillLevel equal to 50
                    console.log (jstore.getAt(index).get ('name'));
                };

                if (index === -1) {
                    // It will print 'foo' because it's the user
                    // that has the skillLevel equal to 50
                    console.log ('Failed');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you [read the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy)? Your `findBy` method does not adhere to the contract. In particular, it returns `-1` if it doesn't match, and since this is JavaScript, `-1` is `true`, so the first record is found.

```
        handler: function (btn) {
            var index = jstore.findBy (function (user, id) {
                // Here's the hint
                console.log(id);
                console.log(user);

                if (user.data.skills.skillLevel === 12345) return true;
                else return false;
            });
```

(This solves your false positive issue, I'm not claiming that your check will ever find anything).

Comment: by this way you will never get the value even if it exists in store because `user.data.skills` is an array.

Comment: I know, but OP was asking why he was getting false positives, not why he was not finding matches.

Comment: then what he will do with true/false, purpose of find is to check whether it exists in store or not

Answer (score -1):

you are having json data with nested array.

`store.findBy(function(user,id)`  will be called for each record in store.
In record `skills` is an array.so you need to iterate it again.

```
   var skills = user.get('skills');

   Ext.each(skills,function(skill,idx){
         if(skill.skillLevel == 100)
             console.log('found....',skill);
   });
```

Comment: How does this explain the OP's problem?

Comment: sorry  - really bad example on my part - if (user.data.age === 71) return id; - returns index 0 and foo when 71 should be the second record.

Comment: sorry again - did not see the "adhere to contract comment. I am working from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444593/extjs-searching-deep-into-store-data/12483034?iemail=1#12483034 example ... is this example incorrect? tia

Comment: if (user.data.age === 22) return true; ... thank you so much  - this works! Was staring at the docs but totally misread them .. "Returns
Number The matched index or -1" is not what I needed but "If the function returns true it is considered a match". Thanks again!